# Migrate data from AWS DocumentDB account to another Document DB account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have two different accounts in AWS and I need to move/copy the data from one DocumentDB in one account to the other account.

Some of you knows how to do this task? I am thinking about do it programmatically but I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB allows you to share a cluster snapshot with different AWS account in the same region. You can find more information on it here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup-restore.db-cluster-snapshot-share.html

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.